# Intuitive understanding of the unit $kg/s^3$ — the unit of sound volume

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, acoustics, units, si-units

I know that decibels are used to measure volume of sound, and they are basically a logarithm of $kg/s^3$. The best explanation that I have for the unit of $kg/s^3$ is that it is an alternate way of saying $W/m^2$, which measures intensity of sound. What is an intuitive explanation for the unit $kg/s^3$? What do the kilograms and each factor of a second represent? Is it a way of measuring the variation in how many kilograms of air are hitting your ear every second?

Comment: Light intensity on a solar panel is the same. There's nothing intuitive about it; it just happens to be the case that the length dimension cancels, because surfaces are $2$-dimensional. If space had one more dimension, you'd be asking for an intuition for $\mbox{kg}/\mbox{m}/\mbox{s}^3$.

Comment: Would you expect there to be an intuitive explanation of why $1\text{ statC} = 1\text{ cm}^{3/2}\text{g}^{1/2}\text{s}^{-1}$? No unit is “weird”. They just are what the math requires them to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every combination of base units has a clear physical meaning.  The best way to understand any quantity is to look at the equation that produces it.  For instance in your case sound intensity $I$ is an expression of the power $P$ traveling through a perpendicular area $A$,

$$I=\frac P A$$

So you correctly stated that the most natural unit for this is $\rm{W/m^2}$.  I could choose to write this equivalently as $\rm{kg/s^3}$ or $\rm{kg \cdot Hz^3}$ or $\rm{eV/(millenia \cdot acre)}$.  The units do not provide the meaning. What matters is the physical relationship, expressed in the equation.